# Read xml element while deserializing c#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have an xml document, where i serialize data dinamically, appending new data if i have a new request. The object properties i serialize are like this

```
[XmlRoot("LogRecords")]
public class LogRecord
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime SendTime { get; set; }
    public string Sender { get; set; } 
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

Serializing is done in this way :

```
var stringwriter = new StringWriter();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(object.GetType());

serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, object);
var smsxmlStr = stringwriter.ToString();

var smsRecordDoc = new XmlDocument();
smsRecordDoc.LoadXml(smsxmlStr);

var smsElement = smsRecordDoc.DocumentElement;

var smsLogFile = new XmlDocument();
smsLogFile.Load("LogRecords.xml");

var serialize = smsLogFile.CreateElement("LogRecord");
serialize.InnerXml = smsElement.InnerXml;
smsLogFile.DocumentElement.AppendChild(serialize);

smsLogFile.Save("LogRecords.xml");
```

While serializing i use `LogFile.CreateElement("LogRecord")` and my xml file looks like this :

```
<LogRecords>
  <LogRecord>
    <Message>Some messagge</Message>
    <SendTime>2017-12-13T22:04:40.1109661+01:00</SendTime>
    <Sender>Sender</Sender>
    <Recipient>Name</Recipient>
  </LogRecord>
  <LogRecord>
    <Message>Some message too</Message>
    <SendTime>2017-12-13T22:05:08.5720173+01:00</SendTime>
    <Sender>sender</Sender>
    <Recipient>name</Recipient>
  </LogRecord>
</LogRecords>
```

When i try to deserialize like this

```
 XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LogRecord));
 TextReader reader = new StreamReader("LogRecords.xml");
 object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
 LogRecord records = (LogRecord)obj;
 reader.Close();
```

I get null value for each property `Message`, `Sender` `Recipient` and a random value for `SendTime`, and i know it's because it doesn't recognise the XmlElement `LogRecord`  i added while serializing.. 
Is there any way to read this xml element so i can take the right property values?

Ps. Sorry if i have messed up the variables, i tried to simplify the code when i added it here and i may have mixed some variables..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your xml file seems to be a List of LogRecords, try to deserialise it into a List<LogRecords>

Comment: If you see the way i serialize, I don't serialize it as a List of LogRecords, so i can't deserialize it into a List<LogRecords>

Comment: You showed `LogRecord` class, but when deserializing, you use `LogRecords`. Please correct typos or show us more relevant info.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov yes you are right, mistakes done while simplifying code when I wrote it here.. typos fixed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try to generate POCO classes from XML in Visual Studio as it's described [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2014/07/10/converting-xml-to-c-classes-in-one-click).
2. You could serialize/deserialize those POCOs using with simple util methods like:

   ```
   public static T DeserializeXML<T>(string content)
   {
       if (content == null)
           return default(T);

       XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

       byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
       var contentStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

       var xml = xs.Deserialize(contentStream);

       return (T)xml;
   }

   public static string SerializeAsXML(object item)
   {
       if (item == null)
           return null;

       XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(item.GetType());

       using (var sw = new StringWriter())
       {
           using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
           {
               xs.Serialize(writer, item);
               return sw.ToString();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. LogRecords probably should be a collection (e.g. an array in this POCO):

   ```
       /// <remarks/>
   [System.SerializableAttribute()]
   [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
   public partial class Log
   {
       /// <remarks/>
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("LogRecords")]
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("LogRecord", IsNullable = false)]
       public LogRecord[] LogRecords { get; set; }
   }
   ```

for the next XML format:

```
    <Log>
        <LogRecords>
          <LogRecord>
            <Message>Some messagge</Message>
            <SendTime>2017-12-13T22:04:40.1109661+01:00</SendTime>
            <Sender>Sender</Sender>
            <Recipient>Name</Recipient>
          </LogRecord>
          <LogRecord>
            <Message>Some message too</Message>
            <SendTime>2017-12-13T22:05:08.5720173+01:00</SendTime>
            <Sender>sender</Sender>
            <Recipient>name</Recipient>
          </LogRecord>
        </LogRecords>
    </Log>
```

Answer (score 0):

You manually add the root element in the xml. Therefore, you must also manually skip it when reading.

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LogRecord));

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("LogRecords.xml"))
{
    // Skip root element
    xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("LogRecord");

    LogRecord record = (LogRecord)deserializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}
```

Remove the `[XmlRoot("LogRecords")]` attribute to make it work.

Of course, you will always get the first element in the xml.

---

As already suggested in the comments, use the list.

```
List<LogRecord> logRecords = new List<LogRecord>();

var logRecord = new LogRecord { ... };

// Store each new logRecord to list
logRecords.Add(logRecord);


var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<LogRecord>));

// Serialization is done with just a couple lines of code.
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("LogRecords.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    serializer.Serialize(fileStream, logRecords);
}

// As well as deserialization
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("LogRecords.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    logRecords = (List<LogRecord>)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

Thus become unnecessary manipulation using `XmlDocument` and fuss with manually adding-skipping the root node.

Comment: Regarding the serialization, i am trying to append multiple `<LogRecord> .... </LogRecord>` inside of root  `<LogRecords>...</LogRecords>` with each request coming... So this kind of serialization rewrites my file for every request..The deserialization above helps, except for the fact that i am adding manually an XmlElement not the root element. After deserializing, i have to add one more property to my object and serialize it again